# How can I get text variable on these buttons working for a chess program

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am writting a chess program using python and tkinter and recently changed the text on the squares(buttons) from text=... to textvariable and now it outputs nothing in the squares. 
The code where I create the buttons (in a for loop) is:

```py
    pos=(x,9-y)
    buttons=(tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  textvariable=lambda position=pos: self.placepieces(position),  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, command=lambda position=pos: self.movepiece(position)  ))
    buttons.grid(column=(x-1), row=(y-1), sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S" )

@classmethod
def placepieces(cls, position):
    black=Black()
    white=White()
    squareposition=position
    icon=""
    if squareposition in white.position.values():
        for key in white.position:
            value=white.position.get(key)
            if value==squareposition:

                if key.endswith("pawn"):
                    icon=white.pawntype[key]
                elif key=="king":
                    icon=white.PIECES.get("KING")
                elif key=="queen":
                    icon=white.PIECES.get("QUEEN")
                elif key.endswith("bishop"):
                    icon=white.PIECES.get("BISHOP")
                elif key.endswith("knight"):
                    icon=white.PIECES.get("KNIGHT")
                else:
                    icon=white.PIECES.get("ROOK")


            else:
                pass
    elif squareposition in black.position.values():
        for key in black.position:
            value=black.position.get(key)
            if value==squareposition:
                if key.endswith("pawn"):
                    icon=black.pawntype.get(key)
                elif key=="king":
                    icon=black.PIECES.get("KING")
                elif key=="queen":
                    icon=black.PIECES.get("QUEEN")
                elif key.endswith("bishop"):
                    icon=black.PIECES.get("BISHOP")
                elif key.endswith("knight"):
                    icon=black.PIECES.get("KNIGHT")
                else:
                    icon=black.PIECES.get("ROOK")                 
                break

            else:
                pass
    else:
        pass
    return icon
```

Comment: Why did you set `textvariable` to a lambda? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is is so it stores the position of the square (a coordinate of x: 1-8 and y 1-8) so that it can check what key in a dictionary matches it. As this is  in a for loop that creates all the squares.

Comment: That's not how the `textvariable` option works. It needs to be one of the special tkinter variable objects (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc).

Comment: how does this work? I have just tried and failed am I doing this right? ```python def placepieces(cls, position):  icon=StringVar() icon.set() ```Then: ```python if key.endswith("pawn"): icon.set(white.pawntype[key])```

Comment: @jwm197: ***"how does this work?"***: Read [config(**options) - textvariable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: I have figured out that lambda is causing this issue. How can I store the value of the coordinate on text variable without lambda?

Comment: @jwm197: Don't use `textvariable=`, use a `class object` for all your figures by inheriting from `tk.Button`, e.g. `class KING(tk.Button): ; def __init__(self): ; self.coord = 'E1'`.